# Does http-equiv="refresh" keep referrer info and metadata?

Tags: html, refresh, redirect, browser-refresh

If I set up a page like this:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://internic.net/"></head><body></body></html>
```

Will the browser send referrer info and other metadata when the redirection is performed?

Comment: Good question - my guess is "no". It's a new, separate request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In testing here, Firefox and IE **do not** but Chrome **does** send the referrer (though this is inconsistent as well), regardless of whether it's going to the same domain or not.

Seeing as I can't find any spec stating what *should* be the standard behavior, and W3C in general discourages a META redirect, I'm not sure you can ever depend on this being consistent.

Comment: The page you linked to says "The odd thing I found was that IE handles javascript and meta refreshes slightly differently than FireFox or Safari. Internet Explorer will null the REFERER when it hits the target site, while FireFox and Safari will both set the REFERER to the URL with the javascript or meta refresh code on it."
Did it change since then?

Comment: @Waterfox  - I'm testing here on local and on URLs, in each case chrome and Firefox aren't passing a referrer header at all, I have one more test on an external site to run, I'll comment again after it.

Comment: @Waterfox - I tested on a remote domain and chrome *is* passing the referrer, which means it's not consistent like I thought...so you can't really depend on this one way or another it looks like.  I *presume* Safari behaves like Chrome in this respect, but I don't have it to test with.

Comment: What is the recommended kind of redirection? In fact, I don't want the referrer to be passed.

Comment: @Waterfox - You could direct to a page you have, via POST, etc, then have it redirect where you're going...all the other end will see is your `redirect.whatever` page, so nothing useful...this is a common way of hiding data from advertisers, etc.  The *preferred* method would be a 301/302 Http Status Redirect, but these won't hide the referrer.

Answer (score 3):

I did some additional testing with this.  I had three URIs involved (all on the same domain):

- `/page.html` which had a link to the meta refresh
- `/refresh.html` which used a meta refresh to the destination
- `/destination.html` which used JavaScript to write the referrer into the page.

I ran the test in several browsers by opening `page.html` and clicking on the link, then observing what the referrer was on the destination. Here are the results:

- **Internet Explorer** - No referrer
- **Firefox** - No referrer
- **Chrome** - Referrer: `http://example.com/refresh.html`
- **Safari** - Referrer: `http://example.com/refresh.html`
- **Opera** - Referrer: `http://example.com/refresh.html`

None of the browsers showed `http://example.com/page.html` as the referrer the way that they would with a 301 or 302 redirect.  So meta refresh can be used to some extent to obscure the referrer:

- Hide the specific page that had the link
- Remove the query string from the referrer
- If a third party site hosted the refresh, hide the specific site that linked
- Remove the external referrer on incoming traffic (useful in situations [like this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52812/users-logging-into-my-site-with-facebook-and-google-are-appearing-as-new-session/64978#64978))

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it's possible to trick *Firefox* and *Internet Explorer*, getting the same redirection result, with **preserved referrer**, by simply using a form with delayed submit.

**Example:**

```
<form action="URL" method="GET" name="redirected"></form>
<script>
   setTimeout(function() {
      document.forms.redirected.submit();
   }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: This is the actual answer

Comment: Worth noting that using this type of redirect can cause the annoying warning "the information you’re about to submit is not secure" in Google Chrome. Should be fine for securely hosted sites though.