# HTTP Referer not always being passed

Tags: php, referer

I have an application which records users visits. None of these visits are directly accessed, 100% of these visits are referred from another site.

I am passing `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` through to the database. Approximately 35% of the logged entrees pass a referer, the rest are blank.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is an environment variable sent by the browser. Some browsers give the user the option to remove it when making a http request. This is not a PHP issue or an issue at all.

Comment: The `Referer:` is not a mandatory HTTP header. Its presence depends on browser settings (or proxies) and for privacy reasons is often disabled.

Comment: I figured I'd get these responses. However, major market browsers like Chrome/IE/FireFox do indeed pass referrers. This makes up 99%+ of visitors. Also, most users don't disable passing referrers as they are not tech savvy enough to know how.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind knowing 100% of visits are referred from a specific site?

Comment: The nature of the application. Site.com passes a meta refresh to Site2.com which logs the visitor.

Comment: re: "figured I get these responses..." yes, by default it is passed. However, anonymous surfing is very popular.  Adblocker addons and other anonymous surfing addons remove things like referrer.  So even though browsers these days send it, it is common for people to remove it.

Comment: I see what you are saying and it is impossible for me to prove you wrong ;) I just would disagree that 65% of users are visiting from proxies/adblockers/manually disabled referrers in their browsers. Just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a user visits your site directly, there is no referrer. It's also possible they have set it up so their browser never sends the referrer.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985579/does-http-equiv-refresh-keep-referrer-info-and-metadata), browsers **do not** necessarily send a referrer when doing a meta refresh.

Comment: I mentioned above how most users are probably not tech savvy enough to change their browser settings to disable referrers being passed. I know I would be making an assumption saying less than 1% of users do this. However, I think it is a good assumption and a conservative estimate.

Comment: well you asked how it was possible, not what is likely. If you're just going to go with your assumptions, why bother asking at all?

Comment: @user you failed to find an issue with why it isn't possible that they're visiting your site directly. I'd say _much_ more than "less than 1% of users" fall into this category.

Comment: Like I said in a comment above, 100% of the visits are coming from Site.com which is passing as a meta refresh to Site2.com. The only possibility for direct visits might be search engine crawlers, scrapers, etc which is insignificant.

Comment: @user Are you absolutely sure about that? What about bookmarks? Crawlers, scrappers, etc. are still traffic.

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure. When pulling these numbers, I'm only pulling unique IPs. I've also taken the liberty to do a random sample of 100 logged IPs that have no referrer being passed and none of them were search engines.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for finding that link :) I am going to try a 301 redirect instead and test against all the major browsers with default settings. Will update with my results.

Answer (score 18):

There are a couple of number of reasons why `HTTP_REFERER` might be blank.

1. You have to understand it's an environment variable given by the browser. Meaning users can remove it or even change it, if they so intend to.
2. Users accessing the link from a bookmark, history or by typing the link manually do not have a referer.
3. IE has also been known to remove the referer in situations revolving around javascript. Such as `window.open`, `window.location` and even setting `target="_blank"` in anchors or `meta refresh`.
4. Clicking an embedded link in a chat application, PDF/Word/Excel document, will also not set a referer.
5. Using AJAX, `file_get_contents`, `fopen` and other similar functions in other languages will probably not set a referer request.
6. cURL, fsockopen, applications that have browser-like components **might not** set a referer.

There are probably more situations when this could happen, I'll update if I can think of anything that seems reasonable.

Comment: in such situation, any alternative method that can keep this info on the site that referred to? i mean the info of the user is aboard from site A

Answer (score 1):

Browsers *sometimes* will include the `referer` in the request. But it is not mandatory to do so (the `referer` is 100% voluntary). Indeed there are various privacy and security issues surrounding the `referer` (for example, if an HTTPS site refers you to an HTTP site, the browser should not include the referring site as the `referer`). So don't rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

When linking from one document to another in Internet Explorer 4.0 and later, the Referer header will not be sent when the link is from an HTTPS page to a non-HTTPS page. The Referer header also will not be sent when the link is from a non-HTTP(S) protocol, such as file://, to another page. for more info go to this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178066)

Answer (score 0):

1. Direct access to your page (typing URL in address bar or from bookmarks, history, etc)
2. Browser settings (disabled referrer or empty)
3. if someone requests page content with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function...

Answer (score 0):

It is common when you are stuck finding why it is missing:
- Sometime your referer is https and you are on http, it will be lost.

Otherwise:
- User accessing by inputing url directly.
- A user has bookmarked and come from bookmarks.
- Sometime user keep the url default for browser (similar like bookmark)
- Proxy surfying may remove referer.
- accessing website as bots (search engine)

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the Transport layer, I encountered an issue where my Consumer Application A was running on the **HTTP** layer while the Application from where I was sending the request was running on the **HTTPS** layer.