# How to determine Referrer for external links with target="_blank"?

Tags: php, javascript, html, scripting

I am unable to catch the Referrer using PHP:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

when visitors come to **mywebsite.com** from an **external-web-site.com** via a link with **target="_blank"**, for ex:

```
   ...    
   <a href="http://mywebsite.com" target="_blank">Link to My WebSite</a>
   ...
```

It always returns empty result instead of the **external-web-site.com**

Does it possible to correctly obtain **external-web-site.com**, lets say using combination of JavaScript and PHP or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php ?

Comment: Please see this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643773/http-referrer-not-always-being-passed

Comment: Why do you need to know the referrer in this way?

Comment: Because some visitors came to my web-site from blogs via links with  target="_blank", and there are no way to track this. Google Analytics doesn't show this info also.

Comment: Romario and Brendan, than for referring me to other posts. I seen them, and they didn't help me. Seems (thanks to web-browser developers) it's impossible to track 70% of external referrers (most of them in my case are came from blogs.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found this problem solution. I am suggesting that i have one php file. So i want direct and _blank link rediret ru.example.com and referred link az.example.com. And i have this link az.example.com/index.php?id=123 i want _blank link from facebook.com or another site my page not redirect. Only redirect index.php

so

index.php source code:

```
<?php
$refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
...
if($id<>null){
...
}else{
if($refer==null){
header('Location:http://ru.example.com/');
}
...
}
?>
```