# How can I trim my URL

Tags: php, explode

A have a delete link which goes to another page, call a function, if the function is successful, then I sent the user back to the page where they clicked delete.

I use this to go back:

```
if ($booking->deleteBooking($_GET['id']))
{
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

My link would look something like this:

```
/calendar.php?id=1&month=04&day=25&year=2014&t=11&v=true&f=true&reserved=true
```

Can I trim the link and remove `&reserved=true` when it's sent back?

Comment: Do you try str_replace()

Comment: Try `str_replace('&reserved=true','',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`

Comment: @rennyrocha: What if `reserved` is the first parameter in the querystring?  What if its value is `truexyz`?

Comment: @eggyal, the question was about removing that code only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than performing string manipulations that could be prone to error, I suggest that you use PHP's [URL functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.url.php) to parse the `HTTP_REFERER` header and adjust it accordingly:

```
// parse the referrer
$referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

// parse the querystring part
parse_str($referer['query'], $querystring);

// unset the reserved parameter (only if value is 'true'?)
if ($querystring['reserved'] === 'true') unset($querystring['reserved']);

// reconstruct the revised querystring
$referer['query'] = http_build_query($querystring);

// redirect to the adjusted URL
header('Location: ' . http_build_url($referer));
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you avoid regex and str_replace because they will quickly fall flat when your URL structure changes.

I would put this in a class now because this is not the last time you'll need to do this (I just had to do it last week) or *some other URL related thing*. So, you should go ahead and encapsulate the functionality in one place now rather than later. You can always change the implementation later *in one place* if you find a better or more correct way to handle the task.

A few fairly important caveats regarding your script and possible solutions...

HTTP_REFERER can't really be relied upon. Browsers are not required to send it and many do not. You can get around that by sending the URL yourself in the query string (properly escaped) or possibly via a hidden form field. Otherwise, your redirect and script is going to fail in a lot of cases! See [HTTP Referer not always being passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643773/http-referer-not-always-being-passed)

You should *always* exit after sending a Location header if you want an immediate redirect... otherwise your script will keep chugging along happily doing stuff. (database queries, etc, etc) To that end, I would encapsulate your redirect code as well and have done so in my example solution.

http_build_url is not available by default in PHP. It's a pecl_http thing. Ultimately, it's not really required in this case and my example solution works without it.

**Example Class Usage**:

```
$referrer = 'http://example.com/calendar.php?id=1&month=04&day=25&year=2014&t=11&v=true&f=true&reserved=true';

$url = new URL($referrer);

$url->remove_param('reserved');

$url->redirect();
```

**Class Code**:

```
class URL
{
    public $url = '';

    function __construct ($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    function redirect ($response_code = 301)
    {
        header('Location: ' . $this->url, true, $response_code);
        exit;
    }

    function remove_param ($param)
    {
        // Do nothing to URL without a Query String (hat tip @eggyal)
        if (strpos($this->url, '?') === false) return $this->url;

        // Split URL into base URL and Query String
        list($url, $query) = explode('?', $this->url, 2);

        // Parse Query String into array
        parse_str($query, $params);

        // Remove the parameter in question
        unset($params[$param]);

        // Rebuild Query String
        $query = http_build_query($params);

        // Piece URL back together and save to object
        $this->url = $url . ($query ? "?$query" : '');

        // Return URL in case developer really just wants an instant result
        return $this->url;
    }
}
```

**Caveat**: This will not retain any URL fragments (ie #fragment) In the case of HTTP_REFERER this should not matter as most browsers won't send that anyway. If that is functionality you decide you need, then it can easily be coded in at a later time.

**Namespacing**: For simplicity's sake, the code examples are not namespaced. However, for real life implementations, I suggest getting in the habit of using "namespace App;" at the top of any in-house class files and calling the class as such "new App\Class();" Especially if you're using or might ever use any third-party code in your project.

**Performance Note**: Don't worry about performance until it becomes a problem... your time is always the biggest bottleneck... not PHP. Value your time more than PHP's time! PHP will **always** be faster than spending your time copy pasta coding. Encapsulate your code (in classes or functions) and have time left to go outside and enjoy the weather now and in the future when you need to re-factor.

Comment: +1 All good points.  Beware however that `list($url, $query) = explode('?', $this->url, 2)` will trigger an error if `$this->url` doesn't contain a querystring: the result of `explode()` will be a single-element array that cannot be assigned to a 2-element `list()`.  Whilst this may not be undesirable (after all, one is trying to remove a parameter that isn't there), it's inconsistent with the behaviour when one attempts to remove a non-existent parameter from a querystring that is there.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks and good catch. The online emulator I was using to test doesn't flag that one for some reason. I am kind of assuming that when a developer gets to the point that they want to remove a single parameter from a URL... they're pretty sure there is at least a query string present. That said, considering the intention to use HTTP_REFERER, I guess I shouldn't assume anything. ha I like your parse_url / http_build_url solution for resilience and actually wrote it that way last week for my own problem, but rewrote it to avoid installing. Lazy... possibly. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: Agreed: in this particular case it's very unlikely that this edge case will ever be hit, but if you're developing this class for more generic purposes...

Comment: @eggyal Oh, agreed. You're right that I should hedge for it. All I do is develop generic code anymore. ha Once I realized how often the same problem repeats itself... I became a little obsessed with encapsulating my code. I would probably even use helper functions such as has_query_string(url) or before(needle, haystack), after(needle, haystack) in this case... but I digress. I put a quick fix in place in the example code for the "no query string" present issue. Not very robust... "succeeds" silently, but I'll leave tweaking for use case and expectations up to the end user. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

use preg_replace

```
 preg_replace('/^&reserved=true/', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: [Remove `^`](http://regexr.com/38of2) and that [will work.](http://regexr.com/38of5)

Comment: What if `reserved` is the first parameter in the querystring?  What if its value is `truexyz`?

Comment: How does this string originally built?