# How do I get the user IP address from the incoming request in loopback 4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

Am new to loopback 4, I want to get the user IP address, their domain details, user agent and the url they are trying to access so on so i wrote a sequence, i have accessed the request context but couldn't get the exact key to find out the details am looking for

```
export class MySequence extends MiddlewareSequence {
  async handle(context: RequestContext): Promise<void> {
    const {request, response} = context;

    console.log('Isnide', {request});
    const data = await super.handle(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the context documentation and the properties:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.rest.requestcontext.html

`context.requestedBaseUrl` and `context.basePath` are probably useful to you.

If you want specific HTTP headers, see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header

`Host` and `Referer` are probably interesting for you too.

Comment: i want to get referer as well, so i wrote this request.headers['referer'], now sometimes am getting as undefined, do you have any idea why is it happening?

Comment: I would `console.log(JSON.stringify(request.headers))` to see. Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643773/http-referer-not-always-being-passed/5643868