# Detect in php if it was meta refresh

Tags: php, refresh, meta-tags

Does anybody know how to detect in PHP if meta refresh was made to visit our page?
I mean, some page have the following html code

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' content='3; URL=http://www.example.com/mypage.php'>
```

And I want to detect in mypage.php if it was realy that way of redirection.

P.S. website with meta refresh is not my website, so I cannot pass any parameters

P.P.S. I don't know exact URL of the website with meta refresh, it can be anything.

P.P.P.S. I am not interested in origin of redirection, I am interested in the FACT of that redirection.

Comment: `<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' content='3; URL=http://www.example.com/mypage.php?method=viaMetaRefresh'>`?

Comment: website with meta refresh is not my website, so I cannot pass any parameters

Comment: If a referrer is sent to your web server, you could detect the redirect origin easily, however IE and Firefox don't do that and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985579/does-http-equiv-refresh-keep-referrer-info-and-metadata

Comment: I don't need an origin of redirection, I need a FACT of that redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sessions or cookies.

Check if it exists, elsewhere create it (to be detected on next refresh).

Some like:

```
session_start();
$currentPage = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (empty($_SESSION['lastSeenPage']) {
    if ($_SESSION['lastSeenPage'] == $currentPage) {
        // Comes from Refresh
    }
}
$_SESSION['lastSeenPage'] = $currentPage;
```

Maybe you need to check if that SESSION persists after visiting another pages.
You can check it (where "//comes from Refresh") with

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]== $currentPage) {
    // do the stuff
}
```

Comment: There is no answer about how to detect if it was a meta refresh for visiting.