# Redirect after X seconds header method: Not showing refer url when using IE and Firefox

Tags: php, header, referrer

I'm using the following code below

```
<?php
header("refresh:1;url=http://whatismyreferer.com"); 
?>
```

and i noticed that the refering url is not showing when using IE or Firefox.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does http-equiv="refresh" keep referrer info and metadata?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985579/does-http-equiv-refresh-keep-referrer-info-and-metadata)

Comment: thx for feedback. sounds complicated to me. I want to referer to show. is it possible without  .htaccess method?

Comment: As you can see in the link from my previous comment, the referrer header is browser dependent, so you can't rely on that. Maybe you can use an alternative approach, like pass a parameter in the query string and capture it in the target server. Like this: `http://target.com?referrer=http://origin.com`. But you'll need to change some code in the target server to do that.